# Installing wxWidgets to Orwell Dev-C++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, dev-c++

I am relatively new to wxWidgets and want to give it a try. I am using Orwell Dev-C++ and I want to install wxWidgets and use it to make GUI apps. I have searched the Internet for help and tutorials, but most of them give too little information on Dev-C++.

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me step by step instructions or a reference to an easy tutorial for installing wxWidgets To Orwell Dev-C++ 5.11.

Note: I am using the TDM - GCC 4.9.2 64- bit compiler

Answer (score 0):

Why not using Eclipse-cpp? It's cross platform and supported by large community and prominent vendor behind. It's can be one stop IDE for you to work with, be it for c++, html, css, php and of course java ....

wxWidgets is also good c++/GUI framework, it provide very complete library and play well with other c++ class lib such soci, asio, sdl, wxSQLite, wiringPi, pigpio, ArduinoJson, and etc...

For working on Linux, this my experience to ease setup Eclipse IDE/Toolchain ... http://yasriady.blogspot.co.id/2016/01/raspberry-pi-toolchain.html, You can develop application for Linux or Raspbery Pi because the binary toolchain provided.